# what is the fastest way to get all attributes from a class?

Tags: reflection, attributes, dependencies

I'm working in a tool that is supposed to generate some Java Code to accelerate part of the development based in a swing input dialog...there is no need to get any further with it so I'm going to my problem...

I need to retrieve all the attributes from a class to check whenever it is necessary to add a new one. I tried to use reflection but things started getting complicated. In order to use reflection I need to compile the class I want to get the attributes as it does not work directly from .java file, .class is required for it.

The problem is that many of the classes has a lot of dependencies! Due to some design flaws some classes are a high coupled, so if I am supposed to dynamic use a class loader to compile a class A I would have to retrieve and compile all its dependencies! And then retrieve all the possible dependencies from the class A dependency classes!

I made a test running an existing ant file to compile to whole project instead of the above approach but it takes about 9 minutes to finish! From the final user perspective waiting 9 minutes every run is not accetable!

Does any one here knows a better solution???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid working with reflection and bytecode, it means that you will have to parse the .java files yourself with a grammar and, well, a parser based on this grammar. It is possible (especially if you do not implement the whole grammar, because many java features might be useless in your project perimeter), but I reckon this is no easy task.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Apache commons Sandbox package called ClassScan. It is capable of doing the kind of source parsing you appear to require. http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-classscan/. Note that it is in the Sandbox, so not part of the Commons Proper.